# Any ideas how to implement OIDC implementation for google provider using Go as part of authentication service

Tags: go, openid-connect, google-openid

Any ideas how to implement OIDC implementation for google provider using Go as part of authentication service?

Looking to implement authentication layer.

Comment: "Any ideas about ....?" is not a good fit for StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best question, but if you want to understand a general approach and how the moving parts fit together, see this tutorial of mine, then follow similar concepts with Google and Go:

- [UI and API code sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

Your early focus should be logging in and getting the token in the UI, then validating it in the API. Then see my blog's index page for additional topics.